# Using enum [Flags] and bitwise operator on [Authorize(Roles)]

Tags: c#, enums

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app, and following the example in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/177416) to apply `[Flags]` to an `enum`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Role
{
    User = 1,
    Finance = 2,
    Management = 4,
    SystemAdmin = 8
}
```

Note that, the `[Flags]` attribute gives us a nice way to get multiple values as one, comma-separated string:

```
var roles = (Constants.Role.SystemAdmin | Constants.Role.Management).ToString();
// "SystemAdmin, Management"
```

The enum values will be used in the `[Authorize]` attribute on controllers and actions, such as this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = (Constants.Role.SystemAdmin | Constants.Role.Management).ToString())] 
public class SomeController : Controller
{ ... }
```

However, the above attribute generates this error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Why can I use the `.ToString()` method and get a CSV of the enums in code but not when using the same statement in the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Because, as the error says *"An attribute argument must be a constant expression"*. That means you can't call a method (like `ToString()`) in an attribute because it's not guaranteed to be constant.

Comment: Thanks, @MattBurland. Any ideas on how to get that working? Or is it simply not possible when used on an attribute like that?

Comment: It's not possible to use an attribute like that. What you could do is create an attribute that has a `RolesEnum` property that is of type `Role` that in it's setter will set the `Roles` string property to `value.ToString()`. That might work.

Comment: Thanks again, @MattBurland. Mind throwing that into an answer and get some credit for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because attributes are metadata, they have the restriction that their initialization must be constant. As your error says:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression

`ToString()` is a method call and so can't be guaranteed to be constant. That's why you can use it.

To work around this, you *might* be able to subclass `Authorize` and do something like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     private Role roleEnum;
     public Role RoleEnum
     {
         get { return roleEnum; }
         set { roleEnum = value; base.Roles = value.ToString(); }
     }
}
```

And that you could use like this:

```
[MyAuthorize(RoleEnum = Constants.Role.SystemAdmin | Constants.Role.Management)]
```

^ no need for `ToString()`

Comment: I got an error in my controller class `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyAuthorizeAttribute' could not be found`